# Saving image element inside a specific divs

Tags: php, image, save

```
<div class='film' id='1'>
<img src='abc.jpg'></img>
<p>blablabla</p>
</div>
<div class='film' id='2'>
<img src='dfdf.jpg'></img>
<p>blablabla</p>
</div>
<div class='film' id='3'>
<img src='fgsf.jpg'></img>
<p>blablabla</p>
</div>
<div class='film' id='4'>
<img src='dfg.jpg'></img>
<p>blablabla</p>
</div>
.
.
.
```

I create 5700 divs with class 'film' with a PHP file. Div ids are counting. Each div contains a '`<p>`' element and '`<img>`' element. Paragraph and image elements doesn't have a class or id.

I want to save image elements in these divs in a folder named 'filmimages' . And I need to insert URLs into my database.

My code should do this.

div with the id 1 -> save the image element to the folder -> filmimages/abc.jpg -> insert into table (url) where id='1' values 'filmimages/abc.jpg'

How to I do it with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're going to want to load that HTML into DOM and use [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get an array of those images. Then you are going to want to use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save it. so...

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$images=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image) {
    file_put_contents('filmimages/abc.jpg', file_get_contents(strval($image['src'])));
}
```

Or something like that. I haven't tested this code, but it seems right. As for your database, good luck, I've only ever messed with XML not any SQL yet :)

Comment: Note: You're going to want to use unique file names for those images, but I assume you know that :)

Comment: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in C:\AppServ\www\filmsitesi\pullimage.php
for the line 5 in your answer

Comment: Edited answer. Added `strval` that should fix it.